# Determine column "I" value of the ActiveCell row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, calculated-columns, selectionchanged

This code identifies the ActiveCell and sends the value of that cell to "I6". With the change of the values ​​that appear in "I6", the corresponding photographs of the students will change.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("I6").Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

I get the value of the cell to appear in "I6" whenever I click on a cell in the table. As long as I click on the "I" column where the student numbers are.

The problem appears when I click on any other table cell ("I14:X43") outside this "I" column.

I need the code to always identify column "I" (I4:I43) of the active cell row.

Thus, whenever you are entering a record in any cell of the table ("I14:X43"), the code will identify the column "I" of that line and its value (student number). Identifying the value found in column "I" of the active cell row, it will appear in "I6", as it is in this formula and was changing the students' photographs.

At this moment, when I write a value inside the table, it will be this value that will appear in "I6" carrying a photograph that corresponds to the value that was registered/written and not to the number of the student of the line where I am.

A friend helped me with this code. It works up to column "Z".

```vb
Sub_ Selectionchange

    Dim x As String
    Dim and As String

    x = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
    y = WorksheetFunction.Replace(x, 1, 1, "=I")

    Range("I6").Value = y

End Sub
```

Clicking after that "Z" column, the code stops working and 0 appears in the "I6" column.

Trying to send the column "I" value of the ActiveCell row to cell "I6".

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)               

    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    x = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
    y = WorksheetFunction.Replace(x, 1, 1, "=I")
    Range("I6").Value = y

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Use the ActiveCell row and always use 9 => "I" column with Cells to get the value in column I in the same row of ActiveCell

```
Sub_ Selectionchange

Dim x As String

    Dim and As String
    Dim row as long
    row = ActiveCell.row
    If row >12 and row <44 Then
        Range("I6").Value = cells(row,9).value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi wrbp, thank you very much for your answer. Your code and the code of VBasic2008 work's very good. I don't now why but with your code, the photografs take more time to change regarding the other code. Maybe, because i have other code int the same pages with Sub_ Selectionchange and paste your code before this below.    
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
      Application.Calculate
   End If

Comment: Maybe it need to read this fisrt and then your code and that's why is taking more time to answer the photografs changes. 
However, it works very good and thank your for your explanation "Use the ActiveCell row and always use 9 => "I" column with Cells to get the value in column I in the same row of ActiveCell" that helped me to understand what was missingwrong in the first code posted. Regards, Luis Lopes

Comment: Modified to accept only changes on student area.

Comment: Hi wrbp, i didn't understand. I need to modified where? int your code? in the sub? ti my code cutcopyode? I'm sorry but i'm not comfortable with the vba language

Comment: I edited my answer to consider only the students area. So this answer should perform better

Comment: Hi Wrbp, as the code will be applied to a table (I14:BC44) between row 14 and row 44 and column "I" to column "BC", if the code also has a reference to this columns, do you think that  it is possible the application could be even faster than just being referring to the entire row (it need to read from column "A" to the last column on the page on that row)?

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Selection Change: Trigger Worksheet Change

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const ID_CELL As String = "I6"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Me.Range(ID_CELL), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Your code for showing the student's image.
    
    MsgBox "Like showing student's image for ID number " _
        & CStr(Me.Range(ID_CELL).Value) & ".", vbInformation
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const ID_RANGE As String = "I14:I43"

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Me.Range(ID_RANGE)
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = srg.EntireRow ' srg.EntireRow.Columns("I:X")
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(rrg, Target)

    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Intersect(srg, irg.EntireRow).Cells(1)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = Me.Range(ID_CELL)
    
    ' If not equal, write, triggering the Worksheet Change event.
    If sCell.Value <> dCell.Value Then dCell.Value = sCell.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, thank you very much for your help and your time. It works very fast, as i need, but i do not need the MsgBox "Like showing student's image for ID number ". With your code, it show me immediatly the photograf of the student very fast when i click in any cellrow (activecell). The msg box isn't necessary and slow me the process. If i simply remove the line of your code said MsgBox "Like showing student's image for ID number " _ , it went wrong. Can you tell me how do i proceed to remove the msg box and rephrase your code, please?

Comment: I guess your code for showing the student's image does something the Worksheet Change event 'doesn't like'. Please share the Worksheet Change event code and the code of any procedure it calls by editing your post. At the bottom, e.g. write the title "Edit", then paste your code and in detail state what's wrong with it (error number, error description, slow, doesn't show image...etc.).

Comment: Hi VBasicac2008, in the menu "formulas", i have this in "name manager" =ÍNDICE('Inserir imagem'!$A$2:$A$33;CORRESP('Aval Final 1ºPer - Olhómetro'!$I$6;'Inserir imagem'!$B$2:$B$33))        . Than i assigned this in the picture to change every time i click in any activecells i the table.